# Issue with binding itemsource using MVVM in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I am using MVVM pattern and I am trying to bind a

```
public ObservableCollection Friends property to LongListSelector
```

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector
            ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}"
            GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource movieGroupHeader}"
            ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource movieListHeader}">
            <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="12,8,0,8">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBoxName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" Margin="12,-12,12,6"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBoxID}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Status:" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

Now issues is when i try to add

`_friends.Add(new Model.Friends
        {
            MyBoxID = e.RosterItem.Jid,
            MyBoxName = e.RosterItem.Name,
            Status = Matrix.Xmpp.PresenceType.unavailable
        })`

it gives **InvalidCastException** so i tried List instead of ObservableCollection. Now i don't get exception but nothing is displayed in LLS. How can i bind My ObservableCollection property to LLS with Grouping.

Answer (score 0):

For `LongListSelector` you need not just a collection, but some more complex structure to support grouping

Look at [LongListCollection](https://github.com/Windcape/Diverse/blob/master/LongListSample/LongListCollection.cs). It's great class that should help you

Usage:

```
var list = new LongListCollection<Event, string>(Events, x => x.Date.ToLongDateString());
```